# MongoDB Azure OPERATOR_PULL not supported

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I am using Microsoft DocumentDB with Mongoose in my NodeJS application, at some point the application runs the following code:

```
Scoreboards.findByIdAndUpdate(scoreboard.id, {$pull: {events: resp._id}}, function(err, raw){
          if(err) return next(err);
}
```

The NodeJS application then responds with:

Operator 'OPERATOR_PULL' is not supported.

The app runs fine in my PC with a local instance of MongoDB, so I can only think it's something on Azure DB, but I don't know why or what I can do.

Comment: Just clarifying: You're actually running DocumentDB, not MongoDB. And you're running it with MongoDB Compatibility enabled. You're probably running into an operation that's not included in the compatibility layer.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this response because DocumentDB does not currently support updates with the $pull operator. We recently added this to our compatibility layer, and the update will be deployed soon.

Comment: When will this feature roll out?

Comment: How long ago was it deployed?  I was getting this error two weeks ago in Azure DocumentDB.